# Turn on/off usb gadgets via adb?

Tags: usb

Is it possible to enable USB gadgets functions via ADB? Especially in a `Release build` device.

i can use setprop but in Release build devices it wont work. Also how do i use the gadgets after enabling it since /dev is read only.

Comment: What do you mean by "USB gadgets functions"? As far as I know this is not an official Android feature.

Comment: As mentioned, it's unclear what "USB gadgets functions" mean here. Did you mean enabling/disabling the USB functionality of an Android device? Or did you mean turning on/off the connected device? Otherwise, could you provide a concrete example? Also, for those who are not familiar with this, what did you mean by `setprop` and `/dev`?

Comment: Not possible with ADB but with root you can configure Android's USB Gadget Functions through `sysfs` on old devices (`/sys/class/android_usb/`) or `configfs` on new devices (`/config/usb_gadget/`). To entirely disable USB Gadget functionality of Linux kernel you need to rebuild the kernel. System properties (`setprop`) only control how Android framework should configure different gadget functions including ADB and MTP.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was wondering since i saw few functins with a file explorer.

Comment: one last question, any way/work-around to use usb gadgets without root? api works in non root ?or perhaps porting? (github.com/linux-usb-gadgets)